# docker-compose configuration multi projects nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm still beginner with Docker and I have a problem with my configuation of docker-compose.
I created a second site on my docker-compose.yml, but my site 2 always displays site 1. And even if I stop the container of site1. Maybe it's related to the cache?
I do not understand why...

Thanks

```
mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
        - PMA_HOST=mariadb
    ports:
        - 8084:80

 nginx_site1:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: nginx_site1
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=site1.com

  nginx_site2:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: nginx_site2
    volumes:
      - ./app2:/var/www/html/
      - ./site2.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=site2.com
```

Comment: I think the problem is because of the ports. Try mapping the ports of nginx in two images

Answer (score 0):

You need to map nginx_site1 to port and nginx_site2 to an anther port.

Now nginx_site1 run in port 8081 and nginx_site2 run in port 8082.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
        - PMA_HOST=mariadb
    ports:
        - 8084:80

 nginx_site1:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: nginx_site1
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=site1.com
    ports:
      # Change the port here
      - 8081:80

  nginx_site2:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: nginx_site2
    volumes:
      - ./app2:/var/www/html/
      - ./site2.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=site2.com
    ports:
      # Change the port here
      - 8082:80
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked using `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`